# Dao is null but only in one case

Tags: java

Still fairly new to Spring (and StackOverflow) so please forgive me if there's an obvious answer here.

Program I'm working on has 3 model classes: Star, Location, Observation. I've got the first two wired up to MySQL and working just fine. I'm testing each one before moving on so the third isn't yet and is using an ArrayList to store the Observations for the time being. However an Observation needs to retrieve info from the Location. But when I try to get that data out through the LocationDao, it keeps returning NULL. However, in one of my controllers where I need to access the Location data to display it, it works just fine. I'm not seeing a difference between the two.

Relevant code:

**Location Model Class**

```
package StarCatalog.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class Location {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int locationId;

@NotNull
@Size(min=3, max=25, message="Name out of bounds")
private String locationName;

@NotNull(message = "Cannot be blank")
private Double latitude;

@NotNull(message = "Cannot be blank")
private Double longitude;

// Constructors
public Location() { }

public Location(String aLocation, Double aLatitude, Double aLongitude) {
    locationName = aLocation;
    latitude = aLatitude;
    longitude = aLongitude;
}

// Getters & Setters
public int getLocationId() {
    return locationId;
}

public String getLocationName() {
    return locationName;
}

public void setLocationName(String location) {
    this.locationName = location;
}

public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
}
```

**Location Dao**

```
package StarCatalog.models.data;

import StarCatalog.models.Location;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface LocationDao extends CrudRepository<Location, Integer> {

}
```

**Observation Model Class**

```
package StarCatalog.models;

import StarCatalog.models.data.LocationDao;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class Observation {

@Autowired
private LocationDao locationDao;

// Primary Key
private int observationId;
private static int nextId = 0;

// Altitude
@NotNull
private Double altitude;

// Azimuth
@NotNull
private Double azimuth;

// ST
@NotNull
private int siderealTimeH;

@NotNull
private int siderealTimeM;

private Double siderealTimeDeg;

// Lat
private Double latitude;

// RA
private Double rightAscension;

// Dec
private Double declination;

 // Foreign key of Location
@NotNull
private int locationId;

// Foreign key of Star
@NotNull
private Integer objectId;

// Constructor
public Observation() {
    observationId = nextId;
    nextId = nextId + 1;
}

// Calculators
public void setLatitude() {
    latitude = locationDao.findOne(locationId).getLatitude(); // Error here - locationDao = null
}

// Cut non-applicable code
```

**StarController** (Where it works)

```
package StarCatalog.controllers;

import StarCatalog.models.*;
import StarCatalog.models.data.LocationDao;
import StarCatalog.models.data.StarDao;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("star")
public class StarController {

@Autowired
private StarDao starDao;

@Autowired
private LocationDao locationDao;

// Index
@RequestMapping("")
public String index(Model model) {

    Iterable<Star> stars = starDao.findAll();
    ArrayList<Observation> observations = ObservationData.getAll();
    Iterable<Location> locations = locationDao.findAll();  //This one works just fine.

    model.addAttribute("stars", stars);
    model.addAttribute("observations", observations);
    model.addAttribute("locations", locations);
    model.addAttribute("title", "Uranometria 2.0");

    return "star/index";
}
```

I've tried swapping out the findOne in the Observation for findAll just in case that was the problem, but since it's locationDao that's coming back null, it doesn't matter which I use.

If it helps, here's the error it throws:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at StarCatalog.models.Observation.setLatitude(Observation.java:58) ~[main/:na]
```

Comment: So your `Observation` class is not a table entity correct?

Comment: The Observation class is just a class. There's a separate class that I haven't posted here called ObservationData that is an ArrayList that holds the Observations. That will be replaced by wiring it up to the database once I've gotten this glitch with getting the info out of the Location fixed.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. I'm writing an answer for you as we speak.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your whole design is a bit off.

- You seem to use a table named `Location` which maps to a respective
  database table and then a class named `Observation` which seems to be
  a super table of the `Location` table storing data regarding this and
  having a reference to the location table.
- What you have in place is not a valid table hierarchy desing.
  Ideally, the `Observation` table should be the top level entity,
  having a one to many relation with the `Location` table. You can
  check online on how to map this relation very easily.
- You do not need an extra `ObservationData` class just to wrap an
  arraylist in there to retrieve the locations. With a one to many
  design, your `Observation` class will containg a list or better yet a
  set that will contain the location information for each observation.
- The reason why you `LocationDao` is null in `Observation` has to do
  with the fact, that the class in question is not a Spring managed
  bean. Hence Spring does not know how to inject the bean in question
  `LocationDao`. You can get around this, by annotating the Observation
  class with `@Component` which will bring this into Spring context
  thus allowing you to do so, but I would recommend against doing this
  (see above on how to properly map a relation between them).
- `LocationDao` this is obviously not a DAO, hence the naming
  convention is wrong. Also it does not need the `@Transactional`
  annotation.
- Avoid injecting beans via field injection and prefer to do this via
  constructor.

I hope all the above help.

Comment: I think this helps but am still a bit fuzzy.

Overall, this is sounding like an issue caused by being between two stages: One where I was focused on testing the math and not worrying about the database in which I'd just stored things in lists temporarily, and the stage I'm working to where it's put into the database and am only 2/3 done.

However, I'm still fuzzy on what *exactly* a Dao is and what @Transactional does.

I suppose I should just keep working on setting up the database and it might all shake out in the end.